# Running eclipse ant targets from an external command

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-indigo, run-configuration

I have several ant targets with custom run configurations setup in my eclipse; is there a way to trigger these ant targets with run configurations from a command line?

Comment: You can run Ant build files in the Eclipse environment using the `org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner` application, but I don't think this uses the external tools run configuration.

Comment: Never used it, but http://www.ant4eclipse.org/ may be useful